# Firebase 'child_removed' event listener not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

'child_added' works fine, but 'child_removed' does not work.

The data index is ".indexOn": "status".

- **Firebase data**

  ```
  {
      "user uid" : {
          "-Kb8FSBMOvcposJ-iJYL" : {
              "createDate" : 1485140252291,
              "message" : "login",
              "response" : "none",
              "status" : "0",
              "title" : "8. sign-in"
          },
         "-KbL6d1xrfqCBAcP7_Qu" : {
              "createDate" : 1485356045006,
              "message" : "logout",
              "response" : "none",
              "status" : "1",
              "title" : "sign-out"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Firebase event listener**

  ```
  var notiRef = firebase.database().ref('message/' + user.uid);
  notiRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo('wait').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      //do something...
  });

  notiRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo('wait').on('child_moved', function(snapshot) {
      // not worked.
  });

  firebase.database().ref('notification/' + user.uid + '/uid').on('child_moved', function(snapshot) {
      // not worked.
  });
  notiRef.on('child_moved', function(snapshot) {
      // not worked.
  });
  ```

All three 'child_removed' in the above code will not work.
Is it a problem to set the ref target? Or is it a problem with setting indexOn? (Setting indexOn is required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that **child_moved** events are not fired? Because that is what you are listening for.

If it is **removal** of children you are interested, try listening for **child_removed instead of child_moved**.

Ex:

```
notiRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
      // probably will work.
});
```

Comment: It is my mistake.
Thought was 'removed', but typing was 'moved'.
Thank you.